# How do you step into function and to the next command using Elixir debugger?

Tags: elixir

Python's pdb allows you to use `s` to step into functions that are to be executed and `n` to go to the next function to execute. How do you achieve the same using Elixir's debuggers ?

The debugging technique that I tried here is `IEx.pry`. I am open to any other method of debugging (including using Erlang's)

Comment: What is Elixir's debugger? AFAIK there's no such thing.

Comment: @michalmuskala There are debuggers in Elixir http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/04/debugging-techniques-in-elixir-lang/ but it's impossible to tell from his question which one he's referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You might notice this passage in that blog post that I  linked in the comment in reference to Iex.Pry:

> Although it isn’t a traditional debugger since you can’t step, add
>   breakpoints and so forth, it’s a good tool for non-production
>   debugging.

Comment: Is there one that can step into functions with break points, something like Python's `pdb` ?

Comment: Did you look at the blog post I linked in my comment?  It discusses several options for debugging Elixir code.